# Conditional PROC SQL on SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have a SAS Script containing multiple PROC SQLs. The question is that the SQL Query should be "adapted" based on a SAS variable value, for example :

```
%let COD_COC =(52624, 52568, 52572);
%let COD_BLOC = ();

proc sql; 
create table work.abordados as 
    select t1.cd_acao, 
    t1.cd_bloc, 
    t1.cd_tip_cnl, 
    t1.cd_cmco, 
    t1.cd_cli, 
    datepart(t1.ts_ctt) format=date9. as data_abordagem,
    intnx('day',datepart(t1.ts_ctt), &Prazo_Compra) format=date9. as data_limite
from db2coc.ctt_cli_cmco t1
where (t1.cd_acao in &COD_COC)
and (t1.cd_bloc in &COD_BLOC) <<<<<<< facultative filter    
;quit;
```

The question is that the second filter (t1.cd_bloc in &COD_BLOC) should be applied only if the     %let COD_BLOC = (); is different of "()".

I´ve been reading about "match/case" on SQL but as far as I know, this test applies to results of queries/values. On my case, what I must test is the SAS variable.

How handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing you want to apply the `COD_BLOC` in-list filter only when there are one or more values, AND that a proper in-list will have at least 3 source code characters `(*)`, you can test the length as the criteria for using the macro variable.

When the `%IF` is in open code you need a `%do %end` block as follows:

```
...
%if %length(&COD_BLOC) > 2 %then %do;
  and t1.cd in &COD_BLOC
%end;

...
```

When the code is inside a macro, you can use the above or the below

```
...
%if %length(&COD_BLOC) > 2 %then
and t1.cd in &COD_BLOC
;
...
```

Another possible coding solution is to use `%sysfunc(IFC(...))` to conditionally generate code

```
...
%sysfunc(ifc(%length(&COD_BLOC) > 2
  , and t1.cd in &COD_BLOC
  , %str()
))
...
```

Comment: Did I get something wrong?
...
from db2coc.ctt_cli_cmco t1
where (t1.cd_acao in &COD_COC)
%if %length(&COD_BLOC) > 2 %then and t1.cd in &COD_BLOC

ERROR: Nesting of %IF statements in open code is not supported. %IF ignored.
ERROR: Skipping to next %END statement.

Comment: If you are using conditional macro in open-code, the `%IF` should be an `%IF %THEN %DO` block.

Answer (score 1):

Two good ways to do this, I think.

First: the easy hack.

```
%let COD_COC =(52624, 52568, 52572);
%let COD_BLOC = (and t1.cd_bloc in (...));
%let COD_BLOC = ;

proc sql; 
create table work.abordados as 
    select t1.cd_acao, 
    t1.cd_bloc, 
    t1.cd_tip_cnl, 
    t1.cd_cmco, 
    t1.cd_cli, 
    datepart(t1.ts_ctt) format=date9. as data_abordagem,
    intnx('day',datepart(t1.ts_ctt), &Prazo_Compra) format=date9. as data_limite
from db2coc.ctt_cli_cmco t1
where (t1.cd_acao in &COD_COC)
 &COD_BLOC <<<<<<< facultative filter    
;quit;
```

Tada, now it is just ignored.  Comment out or delete the second line if you want it to be used (and put values in the ... ).

Second, the more proper way, is to use the macro language.  This is more commonly done *in* a macro, but in 9.4m7 (the newest release, and a few years old now) you can do this in open code.

```
%let COD_COC =(52624, 52568, 52572);
%let COD_BLOC = ();

proc sql; 
create table work.abordados as 
    select t1.cd_acao, 
    t1.cd_bloc, 
    t1.cd_tip_cnl, 
    t1.cd_cmco, 
    t1.cd_cli, 
    datepart(t1.ts_ctt) format=date9. as data_abordagem,
    intnx('day',datepart(t1.ts_ctt), &Prazo_Compra) format=date9. as data_limite
from db2coc.ctt_cli_cmco t1
where (t1.cd_acao in &COD_COC)
%if %sysevalf(%superq(COD_BLOC) ne %nrstr(%(%)),boolean) %then %do;
and (t1.cd_bloc in &COD_BLOC) <<<<<<< facultative filter  
%end;  
;quit;
```

You have to be careful with the `ne ()` bit because `()` are macro language syntax elements, hence the long `%nrstr` to make sure they're properly considered characters.  (`%str` would be okay too, I just default to `%nrstr`.)

Comment: Just add quotes.  `%if "%superq(cod_bloc)" ne "()" %then ...`

Comment: On your example : %if %sysevalf(%superq(COD_BLOC) ne %nrstr(%(%))
and (t1.cd_bloc in &COD_BLOC)

I got ERROR: Nesting of %IF statements in open code is not supported. %IF ignored.
ERROR: Skipping to next %END statement

Comment: @Tom That does work, but I don't like to do that; it's misleading.  The `%nrstr` option is more proper, and doesn't end up with people thinking quotes are a part of the macro language in a meaningful way.

Comment: @FábioRB Looks like I missed something in the copy - should be correct now.